# Lamp with mod_fastcgi

Tags: apache, module, lamp, fastcgi

I am building a cgi application, and now I would like it to be like an application that stands and parses each connection, with this, I can have all session variables saved in memory instead of saving them to file(or anyother place) and loading them again on a new connection

I am using lamp within a linux vmware but I can't seem to find how to install the module for it to work and what to change in the httpd.conf. I tried to compile the module, but I couldn't because my apache isn't a regular instalation, its a lamp already built one, and it seems that the mod needs the apache directory to be compiled.  I saw some coding examples out there, so I guess is not that hard once its runing ok with Apache

Can you help me with this please?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Note that mod_fcgid is used rather than mod_fastcgi these days (for FastCGI).  mod_fcgid is an Apache server subproject whereas mod_fastcgi is third party and (I'm sure I've read somewhere) less up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Using FastCGI just means that you spawn a number of processes which will handle requests they get from the actual webserver instead of the webserver spawning a new process whenever a request arrives.

Use something like memcached if you want to keep stuff like sessions in memory.

Comment: Can you direct me some examples of this memcached, please?

Comment: Another thing, I was reading about it, and it seems to be a server that must be runing in order to stuff be cached. It led me thinking... I guess I can find hosts that uses fastcgi(I am not sure, thought), but only private ones I can install this memcached... right?

Comment: You need shell access to start memcached. But you won't be able to run non-standard (most hosts only support PHP) fastcgi apps anyway on the most hosts where you don't have shell access.